# How to Use Neo4j 3.4.12 Community Version in Neo4j Desktop 1.5.8?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working in a Windows environment and looking to use Neo4j 3.4.12 community version for my project. However, I have encountered a challenge with Neo4j Desktop. I am using Neo4j Desktop version 1.5.8, and it seems to support only 4.x versions of Neo4j community edition. I am seeking advice on how to run the 3.x version, specifically 3.4.12, on this version of Neo4j Desktop.

Additionally, I have downloaded the Neo4j-community-3.4.12-windows.zip file separately. Is there a way to load this file directly into Neo4j Desktop? I would appreciate any guidance on integrating this specific version of Neo4j into my current setup.

I have not been able to find relevant documentation or previous questions addressing this specific scenario. Any insights or instructions would be greatly helpful.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

After installing Neo4j Desktop 1.5.8 on my Windows machine, I expected to be able to use the Neo4j 3.4.12 community version with it. My first step was to search for the 3.4.12 version within the Neo4j Desktop interface, expecting it to be available for installation or integration. However, to my surprise, I found that Neo4j Desktop only listed versions 4.x and above in its dropdown menu for database versions, with no option for earlier versions like 3.4.12.

Subsequently, I downloaded the Neo4j-community-3.4.12-windows.zip file separately, thinking that I could manually add this version to Neo4j Desktop. I attempted to load this file into Neo4j Desktop, but there was no clear or straightforward option to integrate this external file. I was expecting an 'Import' or 'Load' feature within Neo4j Desktop that would allow me to use the downloaded 3.4.12 version, but I couldn't find such an option.

As a result, I'm currently unable to use Neo4j 3.4.12 with Neo4j Desktop 1.5.8, which is a critical requirement for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest Neo4j desktop won't let you download a 3.4 neo4j because 3.4 has been out of support for several years now.

You have what you need to install 3.4.12 though. Forget desktop and use the zip file you downloaded, that has everything you need. The 3.4 windows installation instructions are here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.4/installation/windows/